# What is the best practice to return a set of static data from 2 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

How do I return a set of data from two static arrays(String, Decimal) to a view? Example [Small, 1.00], [Medium, 3.00], [Large, 7.50].

I have been looking at Tuple<> which does return the data to the controller but I don't think it is the correct method as I would have to create new properties in my Viewmodel to then assign data to return to view.

class :

```
public class BoxSizeViewModel
{

    public static Tuple<string[], decimal[]> GetDetails()
    {
        string[] Size = { "S", "M", "L" };
        decimal[] Price = { 1, 3, 7.50 };

        return new Tuple<string[], decimal[]>(Size, Price);
    }
}
```

I Am trying to assign the size and price to IEnumerable that I can return to a view.

Comment: you can return class with size and price property

Comment: If those sizes match up with the prices why not use a `Tuple<string, decimal>[]` instead or better yet use value tuples `(string Size, decimal Price)[]` or create a class to contain the size and price values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off using a new class or struct for holding the info you want to display. Still, if you want to use tuples, you should return a List of Tuples, instead of a Tuple of strings, like so:

`List<Tuple<string, decimal>>`

I still believe this will be more readable though:

```
public class ProductInfo 
{
   public string Size { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public static List<ProductInfo> GetDetails()
{
 ...
}
```

As for the matter of combining your lists, the Linq Zip operation is what you need.

Check the code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qyryvY